# Flutter: Inkwell does not work with Card

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement and inkWell wrap on a card widget, but it does not work at all. I am leaving on tap as null because this class takes 3 arguments that I populate later on to generate multiple cards. 
I cannot see what is going on that is preventing InkWell from rippling, so any help would be appreciated.

```
class FeedBackCardsImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final String cardTitle;
  final String cardTag;

  FeedBackCardsImage({
    this.imagePath,
    this.cardTitle,
    this.cardTag,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return InkWell(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Card(
              child: new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new SizedBox(
                      height: 184.0,
                      child: new Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Positioned.fill(
                            child: new Image.asset(
                              imagePath,
                              //package: destination.assetPackage,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                        7.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Text(
                        cardTitle,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                        0.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Text(
                        cardTag,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        onTap: null,

      );



  }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Explanation :

> "What's going on is that the Material spec says that the splashes are
>   actually ink on the Material. So when we splash, what we do is we
>   literally have the Material widget do the splash. If you have
>   something on top of the Material, we splash under it, and you can't
>   see it."

Workaround :

```
return Stack(children: <Widget>[
            new Card(
              child: new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new SizedBox(
                      height: 184.0,
                      child: new Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Positioned.fill(
                            child: new Image.asset(
                              imagePath,
                              //package: destination.assetPackage,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                        7.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Text(
                        cardTitle,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(
                        0.0,
                      ),
                      child: new Text(
                        cardTag,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Positioned.fill(
                child: new Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: new InkWell(
                      onTap: () => null,
                    )))
          ]);
```

Comment: This will no identify gestures of components in the Card.

Answer (score 69):

I finally got this to work by specifying the same border radius in both the parent card widget and the child inkwell widget. The other solutions don't correctly render rounded corners for the ink well animation. The below worked perfectly for me:

```dart
Card(
  elevation: 2,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  ),
  child: InkWell(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    onTap: (){},
    child: Container(
      height: 58,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: try adding an image inside your card (or inside your InkWell instead of the Container) and check if the splash works :)

Comment: @diegoveloper wrap Ink.image() to your image.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks mate

Comment: This answer should be accepted! Perfect!

Comment: I was searching this for 1 year, thanks mate.

Comment: It's better to use `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` inside a `Card` to avoid the code duplication of `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)`. It will always clip the InkWell ripple correctly no matter the Card's radius is.

Answer (score 18):

- #### Rounded `Card` (without image):

  [image]

  ```dart
  final borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(24);

  Card(
    color: Colors.blue, // Backgrond color
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: borderRadius,
      splashColor: Colors.red, // Splash color
      onTap: () {},
      child: Ink(width: 100, height: 100), 
    ),
  )
  ```
- #### Rounded `Card` (with image):

  [image]

  ```dart
  final borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(24);

  Card(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: borderRadius,
      splashColor: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.7), // Splash color
      onTap: () {},
      child: Ink(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: AssetImage('assets/chocolate_image.png'), // Background image
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

Comment: Instead of using `borderRadius` three times, you could have wrapped entire `Card` in a `ClipRRrect` and then given it a `borderRadius` just one time, but it will not be that efficient in clipping if the radius increases, say from `24` to `72`.

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me figured it out!

Comment: @CopsOnRoad the bad thing with `ClipRRect` is it will also clip shadows if `elevation:` property is used. And the second downside is the clickable area will remain square even if you make a circle clip.
The solution here is to keep `shape: ...` with radius in a Card and add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to it. It will clip both image and ripple correctly.

Answer (score 13):

Okay so how I did it was I just put my Inkwell inside the card.
Before the tree was like

> Inkwell -> Card -> Container.

Inkwell Ripple effect didn't work on the above one, so I did was

> Card -> Material -> Inkwell -> Container

*Let me show in code*

### Before

```
Card(
     margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
     ),
    child: Container(
     // My design code here
    )
)
```

### After

```
Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  child: Material(
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.orange,
      onTap: (){
        print('Tapped!');
      },
      child: Container(
        // My design code here
      )
     ),
    ),
  ),
```

I hope this helps! :) Let me know if any questions!

Comment: For the Material Widget set the `color: Colors.transparent` or it will interfere with the card color

Comment: `Card` already uses `Material` under the hood so putting an extra `Material` into the widget tree here is redundant. The key was just to place 'Card -> Inkwell' in this exact order, not vice versa.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution is to have an **Inkwell** widget with a child **Container** that contains **your widget**.

The important part here is that your **onTap** property on the **InkWell** widget **cannot be null!**

**Example**:

```dart
Card(
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              icon,
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                child: Text('I'm a card Widget'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

For widget that have tap property to ripple, it shouldn't have a null on onTap method. Give the onTap something like ()=>null;
Hope Answered!

Answer (score 2):

To see ripple animation on card try to change `onTap: null` to `onTap: () {}`

Answer (score 2):

i know that this is an old post, for those who are facing the same problem , what you need to do is to stack the InkWell on top of the Custom Widget you have created , give the Material app a transparent background

```
Stack( children: <Widget>[
       YourWidget(),//            
        Container(         
          width: width,// full width
          height: width,// full height of the container the stack is in
            child: Material(
              // animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds:800),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
               Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('Tap'),
    ));
            },
            highlightColor:  Colors.red,
            hoverColor: Colors.red,
            focusColor: Colors.red,
            child: Text("wow"),
          ),
        ))
      ],
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using card and inkwell you can put your widget content in a `raised button` and use the `onPressed` instead of the on tap.
then you can specify a costume shape and the ripple will have the same shape.

```java
RaisedButton(
  elevation: 20,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  onPressed: (){},
  shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
  ),
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //raised button aligns to center automaticaly so you can use alignment so the widget will be aligned the way you want
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
    child: Text("cool"),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Inkwell ripple effect (splash) on a card that has an image over it, you can use Ink.image class for this..This works well..

```
Card(
  child: Ink.image(
     image: AssetImage('images/dog.jpeg'),
     fit: BoxFit.contain,
     height: 100,
     child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(.2),
        onTap: () {},
     ),
   ),
 )
```