# Ripple effect not working with when wrapping a Card in InkWell

Tags: flutter, dart

After doing a bit of research, I tried to wrap ListTiles with `InkWell` to get the `onTap` ripple effect, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have:

```
return AnimationLimiter(
      child: Scrollbar(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: widget.myItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
            position: index,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: SlideAnimation(
              verticalOffset: 50.0,
              child: FadeInAnimation(
                child: Material(
                  /// child: Ink( also tried with Ink and no Ink and no Material just InkWell but no ripple
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]),
                    splashColor: Colors.red,
                    child: Card(   
                      child: _itemTile(index),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The `ListTile`:

```
  return ListTile(
      dense: true,
      trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      leading: category,
      title: Text(
        item.title,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I managed to get the ripple effect working by doing onTap: () => {} to the InkWell. But after adding the GestureDetector, the Ripple is gone again.

```
             child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                onTap: () {},
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]),
                  child: _itemTile(index),
                ),
              ),
```

I even tried this, ripple works, but it the `widget.nav` function doesn't get called:

```
Stack(
              children: [
                Card(
                  elevation: 1,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, left: 2.0, right: 2.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]);
                    },
                    child: _itemTile(index),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () => {},
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
```

Edit* Adding the nav function:

```
_navToItem(item) {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Item(
        items: _activityItems.length > 0 ? _activityItems : _items,
        showAd: false,
        user: userStream,
        item: item,
        favorites: _favorites,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Inkwell does not work with Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508438/flutter-inkwell-does-not-work-with-card)

Comment: Yes. A little. But still very weird that I can't make it work. I edited my question.

Comment: You have to be sure ```onTap``` is not null, (ie:```widget.nav(widget.myItems[index])``` is not null)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by widget.nav not being null. It's not null. It's  a function that redirects to another page. Anyway this is very weird behaviour IMO. Why would `onTap: () => {}` show the ripple and `onTap: () = {widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]}` not show it ...

Comment: So do you say this ```widget.nav(widget.myItems[index])``` is working by taping on the InkWell ? but no ripple effect?

Comment: Yes. When adding `widget.nav...` to the `InkWell` `onTap`, the function gets called without ripple. Removing it shows the ripple, but it's useless :)

Comment: sorry if this is stupid, but since ```(){}``` worked, try ```onTap: () { widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]);}```

Comment: Still no ripple. Thanks.

Comment: ListTile has a ripple effect by default, so you shouldn't need to add an inkwell. If there isn't a ripple, one of the children is probably causing some issues. Try removing some and see if that helps.

Comment: That's so weird. I'm sure I tried that ... That's how I had it initially. Without an InkWell. Thank you. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListTile has a ripple effect by default, so you shouldn't need to add an inkwell. If there isn't a ripple, one of the children is probably causing some issues. Try removing some and see if that helps.

[Example](https://dartpad.dev/1b6397bd70b9c9c053a682649ffd13eb?null_safety=true)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in using the Stack.

It's necessary due to the way the widget tree is rendered from bottom up, layering each widget on top of each other (which blocks the visual effect of splash if there are children below it.)

The `GestureDetector` you have in your Stack example won't ever get the tap gesture, cause InkWell below it is taking the event.

Something like this work for you?  (Move your `widget.nav` call to the `InkWell onTap:`.)

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Card(
              elevation: 1,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, left: 2.0, right: 2.0),
                // GESTUREDETECTOR Removed ****************
                child: Text('itemTile goes here'),
              ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print('InkWell tapped! Put widget.nav here!'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Comment: No ... still not working. Once I add the widget.nav the ripple doesn't show. I added the nav function to the question. Maybe that has something to do with this.

Comment: When you have a different function in `onTap`, do you get a splash? (I just tested with a `Navigator.push()` function for `onTap`, and splash still showed fine for me.

Comment: Another thing to try to eliminate possibilities is get rid of AnimationLimiter.  (Although I tested with & without and it didn't make a difference in my test setup.).  The description for it seems awfully suspiscious on first glance: "*AnimationLimiter is an InheritedWidget that prevents the children widgets to be animated if they don't appear in the first frame where AnimationLimiter is built.*" And splash effect is an animation I believe.

Comment: So you tested and it shows the ripple? Only thing I saw on my end is that if  I remove the `Navigation.push( ...` from `_navToItem` the ripple shows.

Comment: Yes, even **with** a `Navigator.push()` function for the `onTap`, the splash/ripple shows for me, using `InkWell`, in the code above.  Any function I used, the splash shows.  Really curious what's causing it to disappear for you.

Comment: Yeah ... me too. I'll add some bounty. Maybe someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand the concept of it. You should provide some margin to the widget to show the effects. You didn't provide any margin or align so it has no space to show the effects.

Below exp. show the effects in all the page because center creates margin from all the side. The Centre aligns its child widget from the top, left, right and bottom.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Material(
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("tap");
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
 }
```

**In your case:**

```
return AnimationLimiter(
      child: Scrollbar(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: widget.myItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
            position: index,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: SlideAnimation(
              verticalOffset: 50.0,
              child: FadeInAnimation(
                child: Material(
                  /// child: Ink( also tried with Ink and no Ink and no Material just InkWell but no ripple
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () => widget.nav(widget.myItems[index]),
                    splashColor: Colors.red,
                    child: Center(
                             child: Card(   
                                   child: _itemTile(index),
                        ),
                     ),
                ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**For ListTile case** try passing custom ripple color. May be your background and your ripple effect color is same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap `ListTile` with `InkWell` because it already does it under the hood. We could do this with a `Material` widget to preserve the ripple effect and to act like a `Card` widget:

```
Material(
  color: Colors.white,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
  elevation: 1,
  child: ListTile(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
    leading: Text('Hello World'),
    onTap: () => print('Pressed ListTile'),
  ),
),
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code

```
Card(child: InkWell(child: ListTile(), onTab: () {},),),
```

First of all `Card` widget, its child `Inkwell` and then `ListTile`.